# How to update all values in an array? -JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to update an array when clicking on the li tag. I've been testing, testing, and unable to come up with a solution. 
I have two tabs: The "Create" tab opens a container that allows you to insert paragraphs, the "Home" tab opens another container containing a "Select paragraph" button.

**Problem**

It won't update the values of the array when I do it for the second time. I.e., if I switch between the tabs and go on select mode again to select/deselect, it will not update the new selection, instead I get the same selection from the first time.

I've created an example so you can look at it and if there is a better way to accomplish this (which I know there is) then be my guest. Link is below the next paragraph.

**Instructions**

In order to select a paragraph, first you need to add a paragraph which is created on the fly, then you switch to "Home" section, click on the "Select paragraph" button, this takes you to the "Create" section on select mode. To select/deselect, click on any paragraph. When you select a paragraph, it stores its position using jQuery - index() in the "storeClass" array. Once you're done selecting paragraphs then you exit the select mode by clicking "Ok" button and it switches to "Home" section, but let's say you want to create another paragraph then you click on "Create" tab, create the paragraph, switch to "Home" tab, go on select mode and select again and switch between tabs and you will see just the first selection you made on the first time.

Here is the same example: http://jsfiddle.net/7mbhnvas/8/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tab">
<li><a class="paragraph-tab">Create</a></li>
<li><a class="select-tab">Home</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="create-para-cont">   
        <h3>Create a paragraph</h3>
        <ul class="para-results">
            </ul>           
        <div class="para-tool">
            <p><textarea class="textarea"></textarea></p>
            <button type="button" class="create-para-button">Create paragraph</button>
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="select-ok-button">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-para-cont">
        <h3>Select Mode</h3>
        <p><button type="button" class="select-para-button">Select paragraph</button></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul.tab li a:first').addClass('tab-active');
$('.create-para-cont').addClass('cont-active');

$('.create-para-button').on('click', function(){
$('.create-para-cont').addClass('cont-active');   
var parent = $('.para-results');
var child = $('<li></li>');
var p = $('<p></p>');
var textarea = $('.textarea').val(); 
if($('.create-para-cont').hasClass('cont-active')){  

       p.text(textarea);
       child.append(p);
       parent.append(child);          
} else {
    return false   
}
});
var storeClass = [];
$('.select-para-button').on('click', function(){
$('.create-para-cont').addClass('cont-select');
if($('.para-results li').length >= 1){

    $('.textarea, .create-para-button').hide();
    $('.select-para-cont').hide();
    $('.select-tab').removeClass('tab-active');
    $('.create-para-cont').show();
    $('.paragraph-tab').addClass('tab-active'); 
    $('.select-ok-button').show();

    for ( var i = 0; i < storeClass.length; i = i + 1 ) {    
        $('.para-results').each(function( index ) {
            $( this ).find( "li:eq("+ storeClass[ i ] +")" ).addClass('p-selected');

        });
    }        

 }
});
$('ul.tab li').on('click','a', function(){   
if($(this).hasClass('paragraph-tab')){
    $('.para-results').children('li').removeClass('p-selected');
    $('.select-para-cont').hide();
    $('.select-tab').removeClass('tab-active');
    $('.create-para-cont').show();
    $('.paragraph-tab').addClass('tab-active');
} else {
    $('.create-para-cont').removeClass('cont-active');
    $('.create-para-cont').hide();       
    $('.paragraph-tab').removeClass('tab-active');
    $('.select-para-cont').show();
    $('.select-tab').addClass('tab-active');
}
});
$('ul.para-results').on('click','li', function(){
 if($('.create-para-cont').hasClass('cont-select')){ 
     $(this).toggleClass('p-selected');
     var selected = $('.p-selected ');         
    var pSelected = selected.parent().children().index(this);
    storeClass.push( pSelected );         
 } else {
     return false;   
 }
});
$('.select-ok-button').on('click', function(){
if($('.create-para-cont').hasClass('cont-select')){ 
   $('.create-para-cont').removeClass('cont-select');
    $('.create-para-cont').removeClass('cont-active');
    $('.create-para-cont').hide();       
    $('.paragraph-tab').removeClass('tab-active');
    $('.select-para-cont').show();
    $('.select-tab').addClass('tab-active');  

}
});
```

Comment: in your provided fiddle, after i create and select in Home, I cannot create any more paragraphs. maybe there is some logic error causing all this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reset `storeClass` to a blank array when the 'OK' button is clicked, and then re-push all the correct values into it in that same click handler:

```
$('.select-ok-button').on('click', function(){
    if($('.create-para-cont').hasClass('cont-select')) {
        storeClass = []; // make it blank
        $('.p-selected').each(function() {
            storeClass.push($(this).index()); // push each one into the array
        });
        ....
    }
});
```

Then your `click` handler of `ul.para-results` would look like this:

```
$('ul.para-results').on('click','li', function(){
    if($('.create-para-cont').hasClass('cont-select')){ 
        $(this).toggleClass('p-selected');
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
});
```

Here's an updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/7mbhnvas/7/)